# Issues with translating certain strings

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a bit of a major meltdown regarding a translation of a site. It's a wordpress site with a WooCommerce shop. LocoTranslate and Avada is installed.

The issue is, that some individual strings of text are not being translated - even when i've changed the .po file (with PoEdit).

For example, there's a string on the customer cart that says: 
"hello USER (not USER? Sign out)"

In PoEdit it looks as such:
Hello %1$s (not %1$s? Sign out)

I'm adding a translation that says:
Hej %1$s (ikke %1$s? Log ud)

It's just not being updated on the site!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong??

There are 2 other words that won't be translated either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work a lot with dual language WP sites and find this quite often. In most cases it dues to the textdomain being called before the strings in question are being called. In theory this shouldn't happen but it does. The solution that usually works for me is to add the textdomain a second time in yours functions file and use a hook that runs much later in the site loading process. This invariably fixes it although it a bit of a hack.

If this isn't working and you only need the site in one language you can create a child theme and manually translate the stubborn strings in the page template.

Comment: Hey Phill - thanks for Your reply. :) I'm guessing in my case it's Avada that I have to translate, since that's where the rest of the strings are.

But how exactly do i go about making the translations manually?

Comment: Find the string in the theme and then replace the text for the that of the required language. P.s. If my answer help, please mark as accepted or gimme an upvote. Thanks.